# Can UIDocumentInteractionController be presented in SplitView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, uidocumentinteraction

I wan't to create an iOS app that has a **SplitView** much like the DropBox app. On the master side there is a file explorer and detail view would display file previews using **UIDocumentInteractionController**. So far I have not found any other way to present the UIDocumentInteractionController than modally by **presentPreview(animated:)** method, which presents it modally over the whole app. Is there a way to achieve what I want intend to do with UIDocumentInteractionController? Or any other method for previewing files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not use * UIDocumentInteractionController* at the end. For images, I created a simple image viewer and other formats (PDF, documents, excel) are opened in a webView.